# How to do lots of 301 Redirect (Tomcat)

Tags: .htaccess, tomcat, redirect

I have just done a new website and for SEO reasons I have to add 301 redirects for all the urls of the old website to the new one.
The problem is that I have a redirect for each old page of the old website to a new page of the new one.
Does anybody can suggest a clever idea on how to do that?
The new website runs on Tomcat, I was thinking to configure tomcat for doing that but I am still not sure how.

Comment: Do old and new urls share the same scheme uri ? I mean, do they have something in common that we could use to write a generic rule ? Otherwise, you'll have to write a rule per url (or use a map)

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no generic rule

Comment: Then, like i said, i'm afraid there's no choice but to write a rule per url (or you can also use a map: see `RewriteMap`)

Comment: What is the old site running on? Also take the time to type in an example of what you need to do: old URL => new URL